# How can I combined multiple Excel files with different headers into one sheet using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have to combine several files (roughly 40), that have several variations of headers (ie, headers in different columns depending on the file, some files with a few column names that don't show up in others, etc.).

I have a python script that works to combined the files, but it simply puts them in the same order found in the original file. I want this script to be able to add a new column when a new column name shows up, and map all future occurrences of that column name with the respective row.

An example of my desired output is below, where the 'Gross Commission' and 'Payouts' columns only show up in the 2019 July file, and the '%' and '$' columns only show up in the 2018 June file (and all of the other columns showing up in both):

[image: Excel Combined Example]

*Each file is for a different 'Period'.

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

in_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
listing = os.listdir(in_path)

files_xlsx = [f for f in listing if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for infile in listing:
    file_data = pd.read_excel(in_path + '/' + infile,
                              header=0,
                              encoding = "ANSI")
    df = df.append(file_data, sort=False)

out_path = in_path + ' Combined.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,
            sheet_name='Combined',
            index=False,
            header=None)

writer.save()
```

Thank you for the help, and let me know if I can provide any more detail.

Comment: When I run your code it seems to work fine.  I get all the columns from all of the xls files in the final combined xlsx file.  Can you give an of what is actually happening for you and what the problem is?

Comment: @B.Bogart You're right, thank you for checking that; I think I overestimated the extent of the issue. From this point; the only issue that I'm still having is that I want the respective column headers on the 1st row only

Comment: With your code I don't get any headers in the xlsx, but if I change header=True I only get the headers at the top of the xlsx file.  If thats what you mean I'll write out an official answer but something tells me that I still don't understand the full issue.  Do you have examples of the problem you are facing?

Comment: @B.Bogart That actually was what I meant. The to_excel portion must have just completely slipped my mind; thank you so much for your help. If you make that the official answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad it was a simple fix!  I've posted an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the headers to write to your xlsx file you can change header=True when you all df.to_excel().

The modified code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

in_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
listing = os.listdir(in_path)

files_xlsx = [f for f in listing if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for infile in listing:
    file_data = pd.read_excel(in_path + '/' + infile,
                              header=0,
                              encoding = "ANSI")
    df = df.append(file_data, sort=False)


out_path = in_path + ' Combined.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,
            sheet_name='Combined',
            index=False,
            header=True)

writer.save()
```

and gives me an output like this with some test data

[image: table]